# Getting id undefined in angularJs service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have followed tutorial : http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/

But, when  I try to save a new record, I am getting newcontact.id as undefined and unable to save new record.

What would be the problem?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/9SSGUlQErLSaCyRVOiQd?p=catalogue - code here

Comment: plunker is not working missed some files please correct it

Comment: Added other css files, other angular files should be taken care by itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add this piece of code

```
var original = {itemCategory:null,itemName:null,
itemPrice:null,purchaseDate:null,applianceType:null,
insStatus:null,id:null};
$scope.newitem = angular.copy(original);
```

and edit the `saveItem` function as this

```
$scope.saveItem = function () {
    alert("add new");
    DataStoreService.save($scope.newitem);
    $scope.newitem = angular.copy(original);
}
```

here is the working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8mPw81e6JQUnUKyIgX1F?p=preview)

please not that i remove the `<script src="angular-dropdowns.min.js"></script>` and the `ngDropdowns` dependency of `var app = angular.module('app', ['ngDropdowns']);`, to get rid some console errors which are not causing this issue.

---

**The cause of the problem**

the problem of getting `id` `undefined` is, **you didn't define a variable called `$scope.newitem` with in the controller**, instead you straightly use `newitem` with in the `HTML`, then your controller dosen't know about this `newitem` until you change any input.

if you change any input say `itemName` then the controller knows there is no `$scope` variable called `newitem`, then the angular will create the `newitem` object and a `itemName` property inside that `newitem` object , after changing `itemName` input say u change the `itemPrice` then the controller search for the `newitem` object and put the property `itemPrice` in to the object, ok now you have two properties inside the `newitem`, like wise the process goes with your inputs, but the `id` field is a hidden field and your not going to change the value inside html, that means in your `newitem` object you don't have `id` property. that`s why its getting undefined.

to scarify,

add a line as the first statement as `console.log($scope.newitem);` in the  `$scope.saveItem` function and check the `$scope.newitem` object, here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cr6d2YVXU1jeH35qFswV?p=preview) to test it

1. press save without changing any input

   [image]

   this red color `can not read id of undefined error` is because we pass the `$scope.newitem` to the service which is **`undefined`**, so the script can not get the `id` field of `item` which is `undefined` in the line of `alert("save"+ item.id);)`. **item is `undefined`**
2. change only the `itemName` and press save

   [image]

   here you will get a `alert` saying `saveundefined` this is because of the alert in line `alert("save"+ item.id);)`. In this line `item` which is **not `undefined`** but the `id` property of the object is not set , so **`item.id` is `undefined`**, that's why its alert `saveundefined`.  **item is `defined` but `item.id` is `undefined`**

**Solution**

create a object to hold default values of all the `newitem` properties

```
var original = {itemCategory:null,itemName:null,   
itemPrice:null,purchaseDate:null,applianceType:null, insStatus:null,id:null};
```

get a deep copy of that object and assign it to `newitem`

```
$scope.newitem = angular.copy(original);
```

after saving the `newitem` reset the `newitem` object to default object we defined,

```
 $scope.saveItem = function () {
    alert("add new");
    DataStoreService.save($scope.newitem);
    $scope.newitem = angular.copy(original);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Great explaination! But, yet, I am unable to display those saved data. I have tried running - displayDetails.html, which doesn't give me list of new items! I have edited my plnkr to show displayDetails.html

Comment: here is the updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/i1jeaOmtzorlfPdOMzLV?p=preview you don't need separate file to display data. i added the table of displaying data in the top of the body of index.html

Comment: No, I want it in separate file only. That's my requirement

Comment: then you need to add the details in `html5 localStorage` or in a `database` if you wish to display in separate file without using angular routes. but those are out of the scope of this question. so please ask a new question about your new requirement.

Comment: here is a quick demo http://plnkr.co/edit/i1jeaOmtzorlfPdOMzLV?p=preview using `localStorage`. thank u for the marking answer as correct. single vote up will also help me ;) thanks

Comment: since your using `directive` for drop downs the values are not binding to the models correctly. so you have to add the values for dropdown models manually in the controller `saveItem` function. here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/i1jeaOmtzorlfPdOMzLV?p=preview

Comment: Again, id is undefined and if i use - var original = {
      itemCategory:null,itemName:null,
      itemPrice:null,purchaseDate:null,applianceType:null,
      insStatus:null,id:null
    };

    $scope.newitem = angular.copy(original);
 id is 1 everytime!

Comment: could you give a plunker

Comment: I have copied same plnkr of urs - plnkr.co/edit/i1jeaOmtzorlfPdOMzLV?p=preview ... this is giving id same, so delete and edit are not working

Comment: here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/hiA3BTempMD7vBjicMxx?p=preview same id gave because, when u back from viewing page then the service initialize again then `var uid` is `1`.

Comment: line number 72 in controller,  `($scope.newitem.id == id) $scope.newitem = {};` there is no variable called `$scope.newitem` that why its.

Comment: How do we fix it? Again define empty item? I get it here also: console.log($scope.items); in controller before save function

Comment: It would be great if you share the answer if you know. Else, I can try it out. Thanks a ton buddy!